# How to properly rotate the axes and translate this equation $x^2-2xy+y^2-5y=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In Morris Kline Calculus book on page 194. exercice 7.e I have to reduce to standard form this equation $x^2-2xy+y^2-5y=0$

Starting with the rotation:
$$\begin{cases}
x = x'\cos\theta-y'\sin\theta\\
y = x'\sin\theta+y'\cos\theta
\end{cases}$$
replacing $x$ and $y$ in the equation:
\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom=} x^2-2xy+y^2-5y\\
&=(x'\cos\theta-y'\sin\theta)^2 - 2(x'\cos\theta-y'\sin\theta)(x'\sin\theta+y'\cos\theta)\\
&\mathrel{\phantom=} +(x'\sin\theta+y'\cos\theta)^2 - 5(x'\sin\theta+y'\cos\theta)\\
&=0
\end{align*}
replacing the $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ value

$$\tan2A = \frac{B}{A-C} = \frac{-2}{1-1} = \frac{-2}{0} = 270^\circ\\
\tan\theta = 135^\circ\\
\sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cos\theta = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},$$
$$(x'(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})-y'\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2 - 2(x'(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})-y'\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})(x'\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+y'(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}))\\+(x'\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+y'(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}))^2 - 5(x'\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+y'(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}))=0$$

When I simplify this equation I get this for the rotation of axes
$2x'^2 - \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{2}x' + 5\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}y'$

The answer in the book after rotation AND translation is $ 4y''^2 - 5\sqrt{2} x'' =0 $

He gets a $y''^2$ but I get a $x'^2$, so I will never get a $y''^2$ after translation, what have I done wrong?

Comment: “When I simplify the equation…” The formula you’ve written here is not an equation. And equation has an $=$ sign.

Comment: Just a suggestion, use ```$\cos\theta$``` for $\cos\theta$ and not ```$cos\theta$``` which prints $cos\theta$

Comment: The textbook answer appears to have chosen to rotate the parabola to have its symmetry axis parallel to the $ \ x-$axis (calling the double-angle $ \ -90º \ $), while yours is rotated in the other direction to be parallel to the $ \ y-$axis.  I believe you have an "arithmetic" error though: your coefficient on $ \ x'^2 \ $ should be $ \ 2 \ . $  You also omitted the $ \ y' \ $ on your last term. The book also chooses to multiply the curve equation through by $ \ 2 \ $ to "clear the fractions".

Comment: @boojum Thank you! so insteasd of starting with Tan2A= 270, i should have use Tan2A = -90

This changes all my signs and make sense. Thank you! Is it preferable to use $-180^o$ to $180^o$ in general for double angle formula instead of $0^o$ to $360^o$. Is one more "standard" than the other one?

Comment: I don't think there's a convention as to which is the preferred orientation for the rectified conic.  It seems more a matter of "taste" as to whether to arrange the major or symmetry axis of the conic parallel to one coordinate axis or the other.  (There may be particular applications where one orientation is preferable.)

Comment: I just did the computation with $\theta = -90^o$ replacing $\cos\theta = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\sin\theta = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ but I arrive to $2x'^2 + \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{2}x' - 5\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}y'$

Comment: So I get doing the rotation and translation $4x''^2 - 5\sqrt{2}y''=0$ where in the book they get $4y''^2 - 5\sqrt{2}x''=0$. I still don't understand how to have it rotate toward the other axes. @boojum

Comment: Rotate your curve 90º clockwise to get the one in the book (it's equivalent to re-labeling the coordinate axes).